# Fullcalendar - Is it possible to set day cell content html in a resourceTimelineMonth view?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

Looks like the dayCellContent hook only works for daygrid and timegrid views :(. 
One way would be to use slotLaneContent hook but having only the day parameter is not enough to have custom content per resource for example.

Comment: What are the `dayCellContent` and `slotLaneContent` hooks you are referring to? I looked in the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs#toc), I can't see these mentioned for any version of fullCalendar. Is it some extension method?

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/day-cell-render-hooks for dayCellContent and https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v5/slot-render-hooks for slotLaneContent

Comment: Ok you are using the beta version. I see. Probably best to ask the developers if they are planning to add this functionality before the final release

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?  I'm in the same boat.

Comment: Use slotLaneContent

Comment: @zach_21, thank you!  I checked it out but it seems to only run once for the whole column, right?  Is there any way to get it to run for each cell?